# Как увеличить размер внешнего div-а при увеличении внутреннего?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, я не до конца понимаю как работает div верстка. При верстании страницы часто один div бывает внутри другого diva. И я никак не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы один блок дива который, например, я создаю для создания фона внутреннему блоку с текстом, растягивался так же как и растягивается внутренний див. Но у меня получается, что эти дивы как листы бумаги на столе - один легко выходит за пределы другого. Как мне сделать, чтобы размер внешнего дива увеличивался автоматически с увеличением внутреннего (чтобы они были взаимно зависимыми блоками, чтобы внутренний не мог выйти за пределы внешнего).

Answer (score 1):

Значит у одного установлено `float:left`, а у другого - нет.

Ещё нужно не устанавливать фиксированную ширину, если хотите, чтобы блок был резиновым.

Comment: чтобы справиться с float:left надо без указания ширины внешнего дива задать overflow:hidden

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
div#big_div{
padding: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
border: 1px solid #f00;
margin: 200px;
}
div#small_div{
width: 40px;
height: 60px;
border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="big_div">
<div id="small_div">
</div>
</div>
```

Попробуйте так.

Comment: Да нет это не то, здесь предлагается  задать фиксированную ширину и высоту с падингами, а для шаблона это не подходит, так как тексты контента разные, на одной странице влезет, а на другой не влезет. 

Мне надо универсальная команда которая заставляла бы внешний див расширяться вместе с внутренним.  например у меня внешний див это контейнер для сайд бара и дива с контентом. я задаю этому внешнему диву цвет фоновый а сайд бару и контенту другой цвет ну вот например как здесь: http://krezland.ru/index.php?page=plati/start.html

Comment: Но проблема в том что, если я начинаю фиксировать высоту то когда дабавляю больше контента он вылазиет или на футер или уходит под футер вообще. А если контента мало то все поднимается вверх что не красиво.

Answer (score 1):

Если вложенность нормальная, то без указания высоты-ширины все должно растягиваться нормально. Возможно, дело в доктайпе, если не указываешь или указываешь не тот, могу странные вещи происходить. Помню переходил от табличной верстки к дивам, таблички верстал без доктайпа и все было ок, а с дивами так уже не получилось.

Если действительно доктайп не указан, попробуй вначале документа прописать:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы внешний блок растягивался вместе с внутренним, вместо того чтобы выходить за рамки внешнего, не надо указывать размеры внешнему.

```
 <div id="main" style="min-height: 100%; width: 1000px;">
 <div id="content" style="width: 700px;">[статья]</div>
 <div id="menu" style="width: 300px;"><ul>[...]</ul></div>
 </div>
```

Высота будет столько, сколько нужно для нормального отображения всех вложенных блоков.

Answer (score 0):

Используй это:

```
<div style="float:left; margin:0; padding:0 0 10px 0; min-height:auto; border:1px solid red;">

   <div style="float:left; margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0; min-height:100px; border:1px solid green;">
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать jquery =) Там устанавливаешь относительные размеры блоков.